Disc Brakes Squeal repeatedly
I have a little mechanical aptitude, so when my rear brakes began to squeal I took them to a bike shop.  They changed the pads - bike is under 6 months old and cleaned the rotors. I broke them in and was good for about two months. Took them to REI bike shop, they also replaced the pads and cleaned the rotors. Another 3 weeks and same story. This time they sanded down the pads and cleaned the rotors. 2 weeks later, I am right back to announcing my stops.
The bike is a Gazelle Ultimate T10 e-bike. The brakes are a Shimano hydraulic disc brake.
I ride about 50 miles a week, almost always on paved/concrete surfaces; very rarely on dirt. Bike is stored under my covered patio - in Phoenix!

Do you clean your bike often? And do they squeal at any speed or only right before coming to a complete stop?

This is a good question, so good that we've already got a post with answers.  Please don't take offence this is closed as a duplicate.
